# Computing "D" for RSA Key Generation in C++

Tags: c++, rsa

Currently having some issues with my attempt of calculating "D" in the Steps of RSA key generation. I'm writing in C++, and the only formula i can find is d=e^(-1) mod [(p-1)x(q-1)] and putting that into C++ has given me some issues but all I get is the following error? is there a better way to implement the reverse modulos algorithm?

```
 int tis case E is 29 and 20 is phi 
 double  num = pow(29,-1)%(20);
```

ERROR:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('double' and 'double')
       double  ju = pow(29,-1)%(20);
```

Comment: why don't use `1.0/29`? And `%` operator in C++ is only for integer operations

Comment: RSA is done using modular arithmetic on big integers. C++ has no built-in way to do this kind of big integer math. `pow` is only for floating-point numbers, as you've discovered.

Comment: *e^{-1} mod x* is modular inverse. You have to use the extended euclidean algorithm to compute that.